# I am able to install docker image & run from dockerhub, but mapping url does not shown (closed)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, docker, dockerhub

I m using docker toolbox in  Windows 7, and when I run a command like
'`docker run -p 5000:5000 -d in28min/todo-rest-api-h2:1.0.0.RELEASE`'
, it worked and app executed.

[image]

-- Here is shown that app started.

[image]

Besides '`docker container ls`' command give me running port.
[image]

So, when I request to corresponding URL(`http://localhost:5000/hello-world`), it does not respond (This site can’t be reached). What can be a problem here? As far as I know, that '`-p`' command allows us to request. Thanks in advance

Comment: Your `docker container ls` response is giving `5000->500` instead of `5000->5000`. Perhaps a typo?

Comment: Yeah, i wrote command quickly, in order to take the situation. But  problem is same, when I wrote 5000. Thank you for saying I m changing it immediately

Comment: Can we see your `application.properties` as well?

Comment: I installed and run it from docker.hub

Comment: 1- What is the exact error you get? 2- What does `ipconfig` show you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution. It is because of 'docker-machine ip'. which is different in docker toolbox. Default docker-machine ip is 192.168.99.100, not localhost.